# is there a way to calculate every possible order of operation for 1 operation in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say that I have `a = '1+2*5/3'`, there's a specific order to which my machine will evaluate this statement (with `eval(a)`)

I would like to know if there's a line of code (or a function? just an elegant way that could get the job done) that would calculate :

```
(1+2)*5/3
1+(2*5)/3
1+2*(5/3)
(1+2*5)/3
1+(2*5/3)
(1+2)*(5/3)
1+2*5/3
```

In this example, I used an operation with 4 factors, so I could just code 1 function for each possibility, but I need to do the same thing with 6 factors and that would just take way too much time and effort since the possibility of different operation order would increase exponentially

It would be also great that it returns everything in a dictionary in this form {operation:result} with the parentheses included, if not i'll find my way around it

edit: as requested, the main goal is to make a program that find the solution to the game " le compte est bon " brute force method, the rules can be found here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_chiffres_et_des_lettres#Le_compte_est_bon_.28.22the_total_is_right.22.29

Comment: Probably not and you need to define what 'every possible order for one operation' means because what you're showing is not quite that.

Comment: No, there is no function that'll do that for you. You'd have to code it up your self (generating all permutations of groupings).

Comment: @pvg i edited my post to make it clearer

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay. then is there a way to generate a list of every possible parentheses location and make sure that "(" is always found before ")"

Comment: What (and why) exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @pvg a french game( not sure if solely french) called le bon compte, you have one number( call it 'A') and another 6 and you need make operations using the other 6 numbers ( can be used only once ) to get as close as you can to the number 'A'. what i'm trying to do is some sort of program that does the job for you, brute force method. i managed to try out every possible operation but i cant get my program to take into consideration the order of operation

Comment: You should add that to your question, maybe with some links to the rules of the game, etc. There is probably a less painful way to approach it.

Comment: @pvg i thought about changing the order of operation, like make + and - have priority over * and /, i havent thought about it before making the post i'll try looking it up

Comment: You're going to have a much easier time thinking about this and manipulating these expressions if you represent them in RPN which is both closer to what happens in the game and also frees you from having to think about parens or operator precedence.

Comment: @pvg could you elaborate if that's ok what RPN is?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be very hard. I recommend you follow these steps:

1. Create a list to check if the formula has already been calculated
2. Randomize the order (such as +-*/ and randomly place numbers
3. Check if rule number`s one is a valid formula. if not try number 1 again
4. Randomize the order (such as opening and closing parentheses and ^)
5. Check if the sentence above is a valid formula. if not try number 3 again.
6. Check the formula through the list and see if it has already been calculated. if it has been calculated then we don't use it and go back to number two. but...
7. If it is not in the list then we can use it.

Those are the basic steps for common known math symbols, but what about square root?

Another way to do this is by making python move the symbols over like you did with the parentheses, but for EVERYTHING (numbers and symbols(+-/*))

**EDIT:**
This was before the original question was changed.

Comment: if somehow my machine needs to calculate something weird like )1+(2)*5)/3, it's gonna raise an error but is there a way to make the program just ignore that specific operation and move on to the next?

Comment: Use a try and catch exception on eval. try(eval(function))catch(redo formula)

Comment: okay, ill look into tomorrow. if you feel like it i could use some documentation for that try function